# Code for finding words fails to create correct output

Tags: python

I want to create a program that reads a text file and searches for the phrase "CATEGORIE ANIMALI"
then when it finds it, I want it to search for "UCCELLO" and "ANFIBIO", when it finds "ANFIBIO" I want it to continue reading the file for the next "CATEGORIE ANIMALI"
Here is the text file:

```
CATEGORIA ANIMALI
MAMMIFERO
PESCE
UCCELLO = tucano
ANFIBIO = rana
RETTILE
CATEGORIA ANIMALI
MAMMIFERO
PESCE
UCCELLO = gru
ANFIBIO = rospo
RETTILE
CATEGORIA ANIMALI
MAMMIFERO
PESCE
UCCELLO = gru
ANFIBIO = rana
RETTILE
```

and here is the code

```py
file = open('testfile.txt', 'r')

search_phrase1 = "CATEGORIA ANIMALI"
search_phrase2 = "UCCELLO"
search_phrase3 = "ANFIBIO"
markerInd1 = 0
markerInd2 = 0
markerInd3 = 0
reserveMarker = 0

for line in file.readlines():
    reserveMarker += 1
    if line.find(search_phrase1) >= 0:
        markerInd1 += 1
        print(line)
        for line in file.readlines():
            if line.find(search_phrase2) >= 0:
                markerInd2 += 1
                print(line)
            elif line.find(search_phrase3) >= 0:
                markerInd3 += 1
                print(line)
                break

print(markerInd1)
print(markerInd2)
print(markerInd3)
print(reserveMarker)
```

Output I wish to obtain:

```
CATEGORIE ANIMALI

UCCELLO = tucano

ANFIBIO = rana

CATEGORIE ANIMALI

UCCELLO = gru

ANFIBIO = rospo

CATEGORIE ANIMALI

UCCELLO = gru

ANFIBIO = rana

3
3
3
19
```

What it really looks like:

```
CATEGORIE ANIMALI

CATEGORIE ANIMALI

CATEGORIE ANIMALI

3
0
0
19
```

Comment: So you are just looking for each line containing category and then checking each line below that for the `=`?

Comment: Have you heard about regex? A single expression could match and extract the parts you wish to extract.

Comment: What are the numbers at the end of your expected output?

Comment: @Błotosmętek those are the counts of each occurrence of the search phrases.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: The repeated `for line in file.readlines():` loops are an issue, since as soon as one completes all the others have nothing left to read. By the way, you don't need to use `.readlines()`, you can iterate over the file object directly.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `with open` instead of `open` so the file closes correctly. You also do not need the 2nd `for` loop. I think that is mostly where your issue is. That and `break` needs to be removed. See below example.

```
import os


search_phrase1 = "CATEGORIA ANIMALI"
search_phrase2 = "UCCELLO"
search_phrase3 = "ANFIBIO"
markerInd1 = 0
markerInd2 = 0
markerInd3 = 0
reserveMarker = 0

with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        reserveMarker += 1

        if search_phrase1 in line:
            markerInd1 += 1
            print(line)
        if search_phrase2 in line:
            markerInd2 += 1
            print(line)
        elif search_phrase3 in line:
            markerInd3 += 1
            print(line)

print(markerInd1)
print(markerInd2)
print(markerInd3)
print(reserveMarker)
```

Results:

```
CATEGORIA ANIMALI

UCCELLO = tucano

ANFIBIO = rana

CATEGORIA ANIMALI

UCCELLO = gru

ANFIBIO = rospo

CATEGORIA ANIMALI

UCCELLO = gru

ANFIBIO = rana

3
3
3
18  # I got 18 instead of 19 so I think you have an extra blank line in your data.
```